# Find the last node in binary heap

Tags: python-3.x, heap

This heap is backed by a BinaryNode class that stores pointers to the parent, left child, and right child. No array is being used.

I am trying to find the deepest most right node. I thought the code I had below would work, but it only ever checks the right subtree because I start out by going right. For example, in the two heaps below, this works if the last node is in the 5, 6, or 5 and 6 slot. If those two are empty it would return the node in slot 2 instead of slot 4.

```
      0                     0
     / \                   / \  
    /   \                 /   \
   1     2               1     2
  / \   / \             / \    
 3   4 5   6           3   4 

# ---------- Find the last element ----------

def _find_last(self, node):           # PARAMETER node: the root of the tree
    # Start by going right

    if self._has_right(node):         # _has_right takes a node and returns True if there is a node

        node = self._find_last(node.get_right())


    # Go left if there is not a right

    elif self._has_left(node):         # _has_left takes a node and returns True if there is a node

       node = self._find_last(node.get_left())


    return node                        # return the last node in the tree
```

Comment: I think breadth-first search might be the best strategy for this, rather than depth-first search. Always give priority to the rightmost child. Alternatively, standard depth-first search.

Comment: It is searching only the right branch because it enters the left branch only if there is no right branch because of the `elif` statement you have used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A binary heap must respect the shape constraint:

1. All levels except possible the bottom level are completely filled.
2. If not full, the bottom level is left-filled.

If you know how many nodes are in the heap, you can use that information to quickly get to the lowest, right-most node. For example, say you have a heap with five nodes:

```
     1
  2     3
4   5
```

The number of nodes in the heap is 5, or "101" in binary. You can use the binary representation to take you to the last node:

At the root, you lop off the first digit, leaving you with "01". The rule then becomes take the left branch if the digit is 0, and take the right branch if the digit is 1.

We're at the root node, and the next binary digit is 0. So take the left branch and you're at the node `2` in the heap. Lop off the `0` and you're left with "1".

From the `2` node, you follow the right branch (because your binary digit is "1"), leaving you at the node marked `5`.

This works for heaps of any size, and has complexity O(log n).

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the last node is always the last in-order element of the left subtree (from the root)?

Comment: @oisinvg No, that would not be accurate. The last node is not necessarily in the left subtree. But it is the last node you'd encounter if you did an inorder traversal of the tree.